# rivets with backbone: calling method (function) on href/onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, href, rivets.js

what i'm trying to do is call a funcation like below, further i want to pass current element (item) to function as parameter.

```
<tr rv-each-item="items:models">
    <td><a href="javascript:selectedItem(item);">{ item:Name }</a></td>
</tr>

var selectedItem = function (item)
{
    console.log(item);
}
```

while searching around i found below discussion helpful but could not solve my problem as it does not implement backbone

https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/554

[Rivets.js: When button is clicked, call a function with an argument from a data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693453/rivets-js-when-button-is-clicked-call-a-function-with-an-argument-from-a-data)

Comment: I wrote an answer to the question you shared. And I have used rivets with backbone in the past. Please share a [mcve] demonstrating why it doesn't work with backbone. You're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working around i found different approaches that can help, posting here if  someone can get help or improve if there is any thing needs to.

**Option 1**

```
<body>
    <div rv-each-book="model.books">
        <button rv-on-click="model.selectedBook | args book">
            Read the book {book}
        </button>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    rivets.formatters["args"] = function (fn) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return function () {
            return fn.apply(null, args);

        };
    };

    rvBinder = rivets.bind(document.body, {
        model: {
            selectedBook: function (book) {
                alert("Selected book is " + book);
            },
            books: ["Asp.Net", "Javascript"]
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Option 2**
Create a custom binder

```
<body>
    <div rv-each-book="books">
        <a rv-cust-href="book">
            Read the book {book}
        </a>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    rivets.binders['cust-href'] = function (el, value) {
        //el.href = '/Books/Find/' + value;
        //OR
        el.onclick = function() { alert(value);};
    }

    rvBinder = rivets.bind(document.body, {
            books: ["Asp.Net", "Javascript"]
    });
</script>
```

**Option 3**
As I was using rivetsjs with backbone, i can also get advantage of events on backbone view

```
// backbone view
events: {
    'click #linkid': 'linkclicked'
},
linkclicked: function (e){
    console.log(this.model.get("Name"));
},

<td><a id="linkid" href="#">{ item:Name }</a></td>
```